# What is a tracking URL and how does it impact my website?

Tags: wordpress, web

On the last days a single domain ranked up in my visit sources with 15% of my monthly traffic in 2 or 3 days.

I don't know what a tracking URL means but it's what it says it is when I access the domain.

The domain is tkpassword.com (no virus, it's cool).

I also don't know if it can impact my Google index since it may think I'm faking access to my website or something like it.

Is this legit? Should I worry? Or should I find a way to block this domain?

Thanks